# How do I extract values from a column based upon positive or negative values in another column?

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse, data-wrangling

I am having mixed results with two different datasets.  The first dput output works fine but the second doesn't.  Here is the first dput

```
structure(list(ID = c("4116fa25f9789e2ce647d5920e9500b3", 
"4116fa25f9789e2ce647d5920e9500b3", 
"4116fa25f9789e2ce647d5920e9500b3", "4116fa25f9789e2ce647d5920e9500b3", 
"4116fa25f9789e2ce647d5920e9500b3", "4116fa25f9789e2ce647d5920e9500b3", 
"4116fa25f9789e2ce647d5920e9500b3", "4116fa25f9789e2ce647d5920e9500b3"
), Home = c("Milwaukee Brewers", "Milwaukee Brewers", "Milwaukee 
Brewers", 
"Milwaukee Brewers", "Milwaukee Brewers", "Milwaukee Brewers", 
"Milwaukee Brewers", "Milwaukee Brewers"), Away = c("Los Angeles 
Angels", 
"Los Angeles Angels", "Los Angeles Angels", "Los Angeles Angels", 
"Los Angeles Angels", "Los Angeles Angels", "Los Angeles Angels", 
"Los Angeles Angels"), Team = c("Los Angeles Angels", "Milwaukee 
Brewers", 
"Los Angeles Angels", "Milwaukee Brewers", "Los Angeles Angels", 
"Milwaukee Brewers", "Los Angeles Angels", "Milwaukee Brewers"
), Price = c(-190, 160, -175, 150, -170, 145, -170, 143), Points = 
c(1.5, 
-1.5, 1.5, -1.5, 1.5, -1.5, 1.5, -1.5)), class = c("grouped_df", 
"tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -8L), groups = 
structure(list(
ID = c("4116fa25f9789e2ce647d5920e9500b3", 
"4116fa25f9789e2ce647d5920e9500b3"
), Team = c("Los Angeles Angels", "Milwaukee Brewers"), .rows = 
structure(list(
    c(1L, 3L, 5L, 7L), c(2L, 4L, 6L, 8L)), ptype = integer(0), class = 
c("vctrs_list_of", 
"vctrs_vctr", "list"))), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
), row.names = c(NA, -2L), .drop = TRUE))
```

Here is the second dput

```
structure(list(ID = c("2f95b45e6f5446c06d55e2eb646da6fd", 
"2f95b45e6f5446c06d55e2eb646da6fd", 
"2f95b45e6f5446c06d55e2eb646da6fd", "2f95b45e6f5446c06d55e2eb646da6fd", 
"2f95b45e6f5446c06d55e2eb646da6fd", "2f95b45e6f5446c06d55e2eb646da6fd", 
"2f95b45e6f5446c06d55e2eb646da6fd", "2f95b45e6f5446c06d55e2eb646da6fd"
), Home = c("Baltimore Orioles", "Baltimore Orioles", "Baltimore 
Orioles", 
"Baltimore Orioles", "Baltimore Orioles", "Baltimore Orioles", 
"Baltimore Orioles", "Baltimore Orioles"), Away = c("Toronto Blue Jays", 
"Toronto Blue Jays", "Toronto Blue Jays", "Toronto Blue Jays", 
"Toronto Blue Jays", "Toronto Blue Jays", "Toronto Blue Jays", 
"Toronto Blue Jays"), Team = c("Baltimore Orioles", "Toronto Blue Jays", 
"Baltimore Orioles", "Toronto Blue Jays", "Baltimore Orioles", 
"Toronto Blue Jays", "Baltimore Orioles", "Toronto Blue Jays"
), Price = c(-175, 145, 155, -180, -170, 145, 158, -190), Points = 
c(1.5, 
-1.5, -1.5, 1.5, 1.5, -1.5, -1.5, 1.5)), class = c("grouped_df", 
"tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -8L), groups = 
structure(list(
ID = c("2f95b45e6f5446c06d55e2eb646da6fd", 
"2f95b45e6f5446c06d55e2eb646da6fd"
), Team = c("Baltimore Orioles", "Toronto Blue Jays"), .rows = 
structure(list(
    c(1L, 3L, 5L, 7L), c(2L, 4L, 6L, 8L)), ptype = integer(0), class = 
c("vctrs_list_of", 
"vctrs_vctr", "list"))), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
), row.names = c(NA, -2L), .drop = TRUE))
```

I have a function that creates a final column with values that are calculated using the Price column.  Here is the result of the working dput with the calculation run

```
# A tibble: 2 × 7
# Groups:   ID [1]
ID                               Home              Away               
Team               Price Points Value
<chr>                            <chr>             <chr>              
<chr>              <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl>
1 4116fa25f9789e2ce647d5920e9500b3 Milwaukee Brewers Los Angeles Angels 
Los Angeles Angels  -170    1.5 0.014
2 4116fa25f9789e2ce647d5920e9500b3 Milwaukee Brewers Los Angeles Angels 
Milwaukee Brewers    160   -1.5 0.014
```

When I run the function against the second dput I get this

```
# A tibble: 2 × 7
# Groups:   ID [1]
ID                               Home              Away              
Team              Price Points  Value
<chr>                            <chr>             <chr>             
<chr>             <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>
1 2f95b45e6f5446c06d55e2eb646da6fd Baltimore Orioles Toronto Blue Jays 
Baltimore Orioles   158   -1.5 -0.257
2 2f95b45e6f5446c06d55e2eb646da6fd Baltimore Orioles Toronto Blue Jays 
Toronto Blue Jays   145   -1.5 -0.257
```

Here is the syntax that I am currently using

```
df %>%
group_by(ID, Team) %>% 
    slice_max(Price, with_ties = FALSE) %>% 
    arrange(ID) %>% 
    group_by(ID) %>% 
    mutate(Value = function(Price[1], Price[2]))
```

The final output of the second dput should have four rows but only shows two.  The issue appears to be with the fact that each Team in the second dput has both positive and negative prices whereas the first dput each Team is either negative or positive.  Each pair of Prices should have a positive and negative number, like dput1.  Any idea how to get this to work?

Comment: "edited tibble" looks like the same as "edited output," was that intended?

Comment: Hi Jon, I overhauled my original post.  Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2):

You could `group_by` on Var_D and return the `max` value of Var_C with `summarise` like this:

```r
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  group_by(Var_D) %>%
  summarise(max_value = max(Var_C))
#> # A tibble: 2 × 2
#>   Var_D max_value
#>   <dbl>     <int>
#> 1  -1.5       165
#> 2   1.5      -165
```

<sup>Created on 2023-03-15 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Thanks @Quinten.  That appears to work.  I need to retain the other columns so I can join with another DF.  What is the best way to accomplish that?

Comment: I tried using Mutate but got some undesirable effects.  I will post a larger dput this evening.

Comment: Hi @Quinten.  Curious if you have any thoughts on my updated post?

Answer (score 0):

In case there are multiple positive or negative Var_D values, this variation groups them together based on their sign to only use one from each sign. I'm also using `coalesce` in case Var_D is 0 -- here to group it with any positive Var_D values.

```
df %>%
  group_by(sign = coalesce(Var_D/abs(Var_D), 1)) %>%
  slice_max(Var_C, n = 1) %>%
  ungroup()
```

Comment: Hi @Jon, I added some context above.  Is this what you were describing?